# Find difference between dates in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have two date/time rows that I would like to find the difference between, and display in the indicated format.

```
10/01/2019 10:15
----------------
10/02/2019 10:11
----------------
```

Desired Result:
`1d 0h 4m`

My cells are formatted as `mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm`

I've looked at DATEDIF(), but that's definitely aimed at calculating differences between larger time frames. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to get the result I'm looking for?

Comment: it would not be `1d 0h 4m` but `0d 23h 56m` unless you have the times reversed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the following formula to output the desired string:

```
=INT(B1-A1)&"d " & TEXT(B1-A1,"h\h m\m")
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect! Thanks! Why is there a combination of `INT` and `TEXT`?

Comment: Date/Time is stored as a double in Excel, with the days as the integer and the time as the decimal part of a day.  So we concatenate the integer with `d` and just format the time part correctly.

Comment: Nice use of the backslash as an escape character!